# Meta tags position for SEO

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags

I would like to know if position of meta tags like:

```html
<meta name="description" content="....">  
<meta name="keywords" content="....">
```

given they are inside `<head>` tag, matters for SEO.

I mean, is there a difference, SEO-wise, if they are positioned at the beginning of `head` or at the end of `head` (after all the CSS and JavaScript inclusions)?

Comment: It's not valid HTML if they are not within the `<HEAD>`.

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [Can the order in which adding link and meta tags on head of a webpage have any adverse effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27576959/1591669)

Answer (score 5):

No, the position of these tags within the head does not affect SEO.

In fact - these tags don't directly affect search engine ranking at all (at least on google where they are not a *Ranking Factor*), only indirectly (by how enticing they are to users, therefore influencing the click-through rating).

More info is available on that here: https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description